# $v$ is Conjugate Harmonic to $u$ $\implies$ $f = u + iv$ is Analytic (Proof Verification from Ahlfors)

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, proof-verification

**Hypothesis:** Let $u$ and $v$ be two functions from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $\mathbb{R}$ s.t.

$$
\Delta u = {\partial^2 u \over \partial x^2} + {\partial^2 u \over \partial y^2} = 0
$$

and

$$
\Delta v = {\partial^2 v \over \partial x^2} + {\partial^2 v \over \partial y^2} = 0
$$

That is, suppose $v$ is conjugate harmonic to $u$.

**Theorem:** We have that $f = u + iv$ is an analytic function.

**Proof from Ahlfors:** We may write

$$
u(x + h, y + k) - u(x,y) = {\partial u \over \partial x}h + {\partial u \over \partial y}k + \epsilon_1
$$

$$
v(x + h, y + k) - v(x,y) = {\partial v \over \partial x}h + {\partial v \over \partial y}k + \epsilon_2
$$

so that after multiplying the second expression by $i$ and then adding the resulting two expressions we have

$$
[ u(x + h, y + k) + i v(x + h, y + k)] - [u(x,y) + i v(x,y)] = f(z + h + ik) - f(z)
$$

so that then

$$
f(z+h+ik) - f(z) = \left( {\partial u \over \partial x}  h  + {\partial u \over \partial y} k  \right) + \left( i{\partial v \over \partial x}h + i{\partial v \over \partial y}k \right) + (\epsilon_1 + i \epsilon_2)
$$

whereby *evidently* this means

$$
f(z+h+ik) - f(z) =\left( {\partial u \over \partial x} + i {\partial v \over \partial x} \right)(h + ik) + \epsilon_1 + i\epsilon_2
$$

so that since

$$
{\epsilon_i \over h + ik} \rightarrow 0 \text{ for }i = 1,2
$$

we have that

$$
\lim_{h+ik \rightarrow 0} {f(z + h + ik) - f(z) \over h + ik} = \lim_{h+ik \rightarrow 0} {\left( {\partial u \over \partial x} + i {\partial v \over \partial x} \right)(h + ik) + \epsilon_1 + i\epsilon_2 \over h+ik} = { {\partial u \over \partial x} + i {\partial v \over \partial x}}
$$

which means that $f'(z)$ exists and hence $f(z)$ is analytic as desired.

**Question 1:** Why may we write the two identities

$$
u(x + h, y + k) - u(x,y) = {\partial u \over \partial x}h + {\partial u \over \partial y}k + \epsilon_1
$$

$$
v(x + h, y + k) - v(x,y) = {\partial v \over \partial x}h + {\partial v \over \partial y}k + \epsilon_2
$$

in the beginning?  Ahlfors says this "follows from calculus".  Crucially, are we here making use of the fact that $\Delta v = \Delta u = 0$ (if not, I'm not sure where else we're using that)?

**Question 2:**

Why does

$$
f(z+h+ik) - f(z) = \left( {\partial u \over \partial x}  h  + {\partial u \over \partial y} k  \right) + \left( i{\partial v \over \partial x}h + i{\partial v \over \partial y}k \right) + (\epsilon_1 + i \epsilon_2)
$$

imply that

$$
f(z+h+ik) - f(z) =\left( {\partial u \over \partial x} + i {\partial v \over \partial x} \right)(h + ik) + \epsilon_1 + i\epsilon_2?
$$

**Question 3:** Did we anywhere make use of the Cauchy-Riemann equations above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For question 1, this is actually a slight reformulation of the definition of differentiability for a function of two variables (what it's saying is that $u$ and $v$ are approximated by linear maps). No harmonicity or Cauchy-Riemann is needed.

The answers to questions 2 and 3 are the same. That is, you get the second line in question 2 by applying the Cauchy-Riemann equations to the first line and doing some algebra.

Comment: Then where are making use of the hypothesis that $v$ is a conjugate harmonic function of $u$?  Isn't the whole point of this proof to make use of the fact that $\Delta v = \Delta u = 0$?  Thanks.

Comment: $v$ is a conjugate harmonic function of $u$ because they satisfy the Cauchy-Riemann equations. Any pair of functions that satisfy the Cauchy-Riemann equations are guaranteed to both be harmonic, so in a sense you're making use of the fact that $u$ and $v$ are harmonic in your question 2 step.

Comment: Ok I think I understand.  The logical flow of this proof is very poorly worded in Ahlfors IMO (rare for this great text).  To sum it up, we have that if $u$ and $v$ satisfy the CR equations (that is, $v$ is "conjugate harmonic" with $u$), then $u + iv$ is analytic.  It also follows that each of $u$ and $v$ are harmonic, but this is irrelevant to what we showed above.  Correct?

Comment: That sounds right (though I don't have a copy of Ahlfors handy to check). You might want to go back and check exactly what Ahlfors is using as a definition of "harmonic conjugate." (I'm actually used to defining $u$ and $v$ to be harmonic conjugate if $u+iv$ is analytic, which would render this whole thing trivial, but the proof you've given suggests that "$u$ and $v$ satisfy the CR equations" is the definition he's using.)

Comment: In Ahlfors, 'continuity' of first order partial derivative of $u$ and $v$ is also assumed.Where did we make use of this continuity?